# Google OAuth Always Showing Consent Screen

Tags: qt, google-oauth, openid-connect, google-openid

I'm building an *installed* application that will have features requiring the Google Drive REST API using Qt and C++. I understand Qt is now releasing new libraries to support OAuth flows but let's assume I'm a student and learning to use OAuth at this layer is a requirement for this project.

In my application, I have a working OAuth flow for installed applications that ends with an Access Token and Refresh Token being stored using QSettings (I'm open to input on whether this is a disastrously bad idea too). The application requires no authentication/login for its own sake/data, but it does need authentication to Google for calling API's using an Access Token. This application has no associated web backend being hosted; its simple and should be deployable completely locally (I've written and included a simple TCP server that will receive the authorization redirect_uri and will run and close when called from within the application).

As such, I'm curious about the best way to make sure that, when a user opens my application and wants to use the Google Drive features, they are appropriately authenticated on Google's end. Say, if I maintain an access token in the registry, and this access token is granted per-user/per-application basis (right?), then how can I make sure only the user the token belongs to is able to make calls to the API with it?

Here's my understanding and approach; feel free to correct me or educate me if I've got the wrong interpretation.

### If an Access Token is found, perform the following:

1. Open a browser page to a Google login domain and have the user authenticate there (this could prohibit a user from being able to use a cached login session that would have access to a token they otherwise shouldn't have access to)
2. If user has correctly authenticated with a Google account, return control to the application and make a test call to an API using the stored token.
3. If the call fails (responds with an `invalid_credentials`) I should be able to be sure its because the access token has expired and the application will go through the flow to renew an Access Token from a Refresh Token.

### If no Access Token is initially found:

1. Start a normal OAuth installed application flow
2. Get the tokens and store them so that when the user opens the application next time the former procedure is used

My issue then is the first two steps if the Access Token is found. Nominally this could be done by the typical OAuth flow but it appears that when using a localhost as the redirect uri, Google will always prompt for consent, regardless of settings for `prompt` and `access_type` authorization query parameters.

What can be done to accomplish these first two steps in a way that my application can control (i.e. not a solution that relies on a backend server being hosted somewhere)?

If this question is too open-ended for SO requirements I can make some more restrictions/assumptions to limit the problem domain but I'd rather not do that yet in case I unknowingly rope off a good viable solution.

Thanks for reading! Sorry if its a verbose; I wanted to ensure my problem domain was fully fleshed out!

Answer (score 4):

If you are using an installed application, I wouldn't recommend using or storing refresh tokens. Storing refresh tokens on the client side means that if an intruder gains access to the client's application, they have infinite access to the user's application without ever having to enter the user's credentials. If you do insist on having a refresh token, ensure you follow the Google's [installed app flow](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp), with the `code_verifier` parameter included in your requests.

**If the access token is found**, you should [try to verify it](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent#validate-access-token), and if verified then use it at the google api, otherwise force the user to login again (or refresh it if you chose to still use refresh tokens).

**If no access token is found**, your flow sounds fine.

A few notes on loggin in with Google:

1. Google will only return a refresh token if you specify `access_type=offline` in your auth request.
2. Google will only return a refresh token on the user's first authorization request, unless you always specify `prompt=consent` in your query params.
3. In my experience, when leaving out the `prompt` query param, the user is not prompted for their consent again. If they are logged in to google, you will get a new access token, but no refresh token, unless you have `prompt=consent`.
4. I think the idea is you use `prompt=consent` if you have no record of the user ever using your application. Otherwise if they have used it before, you may prefer to use `prompt=select_account` to allow the user to select which account he wants to use in case he has more then one, or you can just use `prompt=none`.

This is just my understanding of it all.

Comment: Therein lies much of my problem. I see it as a bit of a security concern that if the user of my installed application has access to a logged in Google account that is not theirs then a) That's a problem of security and they now have access to someone else's private Google data and b) My application won't behave as desired because all cloud synchronizing/pushing/pulling of files will be done to an account they otherwise may not have access to. I understand these two concerns aren't necessarily my fault but I feel like there should be more I can do on my app's side to preemptively prevent them.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you wouldn't recommend storing refresh tokens? The installed app flow link you posted (which I've gone through extensively myself) explicitly notes that "Your application should store both tokens in a secure, long-lived location that is accessible between different invocations of your application." I did raise the question in my OP if the registry would be a good place to do that and...I've decided to instead store them in a (soon-to-be-encrypted) SQLite db file on a per-user-record basis.

Answer (score 0):

My approach I ended up using was just to deploy with an SQLite db that will be stored in the AppData roaming directory. The db schema includes a field for the user's Name (from the OpenID IDToken field if it exists), the user's picture URL (again from IDToken if it exists), the refresh and access token strings (will be stored as encrypted strings when I get around to it), the user's UID/sub string, and a field for a user name and password.

These latter two fields are authentication fields for within my own application, which, again, I wanted to avoid but it seems impossible to do so. So the user will be prompted to enter a username and password into a form, and these credentials will be checked against the existing SQLite db file mentioned previously.

- If they exist and are correct, the user gets logged in and will have access to their respective access and refresh token.
- If the user has forgotten their password, they'll be asked for reconsent (going through the installed app flow again), and whatever password they provided during initial login will be used as the reset password. It is considered, for my purposes, that logging into Google for the installed app flow is proof enough that the user account belongs to them and they should have authorization to reset the password.
- If the user is a new user and doesn't have a record in the local SQLite db file, then they can also click a button to "Create New Account" - which effectively goes through the authorization flow as well but this time a whole new record is posted to the SQLite db with the appropriate fields filled.

There's still more optimization that could be done but at least I am getting closer to the level of security and control of access to Google user accounts that I want.

I'm not marking this as an answer because I feel like this solution is still not desired and that there should be an easier way. So if someone has evidence or experience of providing an equivalent level of authentication control without needing to maintain a local user account database then I would be more than happy to mark such a method as the solution!

Thanks again!